# Javascript Date and java.util.Date constructor argument

Tags: java, javascript, date, timezone

Yes, another question about Date in Java and Javascript.

The timezone is GMT+4 (Moscow) both in Java and Browser (Chrome).

```
<script language="javascript">
  var d = new Date(170798400000);
  document.write(d);
</script>
```

Gives: Sun Jun 01 1975 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (Russian Standard Time)

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date(170798400000L); // the same epoch value!
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

Gives: Sat May 31 23:00:00 MSK 1975

If I change the epoch value to something like 2011-2012 year (after daylight saving was canceled in Russia) the output is OK. Timezone updater tool ran OK.

**Is this a bug or documented feature? Is there any way to handle this except formatting and re-parsing like YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:SS or so?**

from javadoc:

Date(long date)

Allocates a Date object and initializes it to represent the specified number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

from javascript reference:

new Date(milliseconds)

milliseconds - Integer value representing the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC (Unix Epoch).

Comment: Maybe this has something to do with "Time zone changes": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_Time

Comment: It definetely is. Is that means Date constructor cannot be used in javascript anymore?

Comment: Well, if one of them is giving the right answer, but not the other one, then I'd say the other one has a bug :-)  Is Java correct or is JavaScript?  I'd sort-of expect the Java version to give the right answer, but that's just a suspicion.

Comment: Yes, Java is correct, but javascript is not

Comment: @user509723: here both outputs are correct. The JS version shows it in GMT+x format, whereas the Java version uses MSK (which no longer exists as far as I understand). Java can be updated with tzdata to get the right 'Europe/Moscow' tz. It looks like JS may not be able to use the correct tzdata (when converting this way): this will almost inevitably be browser dependent (and perhaps depend on the OS and the user settings).

Comment: both tzdata and jdk (using timezone updater tool) were updated so Java knows that before 2011 it was GMT+3 but GMT+4 after 2011. It seems Javascript is missing this information and thinks that it was always GMT+4. I can hack JSON serializer to insert a condition and adjust the time zone but wondering is there a better way?

Comment: No, Daylight Saving Time (+04:00) was not canceled in 2011. Just the opposite.  DST was made permanent, in effect year round. It was *Standard Time* (+03:00) that was canceled. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_Time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a bug or documented feature?

This is not a bug with Javascript. At least, I see no way I could claim that.

The browser's Javascript engine is returning the time converted to "GMT+4". What you are wanting, apparently, is MSK which is different from GMT+4 (as noted in your comment). Javascript not knowing about MSK doesn't count as a bug, but a lack of a feature. Perhaps js is "wrong" for not having that detailed knowledge of timezones, but it's not a bug.

> Is there any way to handle this except formatting and re-parsing like YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:SS or so?

Keeping track of all the arbitrary details of timezones requires a lot of work. I know of no such codebase which has all that work available for javascript. Therefore, I believe that, yes, you would have to manually code that conversion yourself if you want to use true MSK.

Answer (score 1):

String representation of time (like `"Sun Jun 01 1975 00:00:00 GMT+0400"`) are used for human. Time value (milliseconds since 1 January, 1970 UTC) are used for storage and calculation.

There is no bug there. In JavaScript, according to the specification, the contente of string representation is implementation-dependant. In Java, according to the documentation, the daylight saving time **may** be reflected.

From [JavaScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.2):

> 15.9.5.2 `Date.prototype.toString ( )`
>
> This function returns a String value. The contents of the String are implementation->dependent, but are intended to represent the Date in the current time zone in a convenient, human-readable form.

From [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29):

```
java.util.Date, public String toString()

Converts this Date object to a String of the form: dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy

where:
...
zzz is the time zone (and may reflect daylight saving time).`
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli( 170_798_400_000L )
```

> 1975-05-31T20:00:00Z

…and…

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli( 170_798_400_000L )
       .atZone( ZoneId.of( "Europe/Moscow" ) )
```

> 1975-05-31T23:00+03:00[Europe/Moscow]

See [live code](http://ideone.com/TBWeOS).

## Using java.time

The modern approach uses the java.time classes in Java 8 and later.

You are using troublesome old date-time classes in Java that are now legacy. Among the many problems on those classes was the well-intentioned but confusing feature of the `Date::toString` method applying the current default time zone while generating the string. The internal value is actually always in UTC, but `toString` creates the illusion that `Date` has a time zone when in fact it does not. That explains your `MSK` mystery.

[Even more confusing, there actually *is* a time zone buried deep in `Date` but is irrelevant to this discussion. Those old `Date`/`Calendar` classes are an awful mess. Fortunately Java now has the best-in-class date-time framework on any platform: java.time.]

Apparently your input represents the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction). This class can directly parse your input number.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 170_798_400_000L ) ;
```

> instant.toString(): 1975-05-31T20:00:00Z

If you want to see that same moment through the lens of a particular region’s [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time), apply a time zone. Apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Moscow" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

> 1975-05-31T23:00+03:00[Europe/Moscow]

## JavaScript library is incorrect

The results of your call to the **JavaScript library is incorrect with its offset of +04:00**. [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_Time), Moscow time from 1930 to 1981 was three hours ahead, +03:00. The java.time framework yields correct results of +03:00 throughout the year of 1975. See [*Time in Russia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Russia) for more info. Caveat: I am not expert in Russia/Soviet time.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).