# How can I parse this DateTime? (T & Z)

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

This is the Date I get from a json:

```
2013-11-08T10:00:04.000Z
```

dunno what's T and Z. I'm trying with:

```
var dateParsed = DateTime.ParseExact(dateJson, "yyyy-mm-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But I don't know how to continue :)

Comment: You can follow this post 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032967/json-date-to-java-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like this...

```
string dateString = "2013-11-08T10:00:04.000Z";
DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
Console.WriteLine("Converted {0} to {1} time {2}", 
                           dateString, 
                           convertedDate.Kind.ToString(), 
                           convertedDate);
```

Check [here](http://ideone.com/ISHm6z) for output

Answer (score 0):

use

```
var dt = DateTime.Parse("2013-11-08T10:00:04.000Z");
```

OR

```
var dt = XmlConvert.ToDateTime("2013-11-08T10:00:04.000Z");
```

'T' means now time data and 'Z' means its in UTC format