# Change the JSON date format to dd-MMM-yyyy in Android

Tags: android, json

I Have a issue to Change the json date format which i am getting as response  to dd-MMM-yyyy

```
 //json response which i am getting in "mmm-dd-yyyy"
    String jsondate = map.get("endDate");

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

 //date format which i need the output
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

 //the json response which i need to set in "dd-mm-yyyy"
    viewHolder.end_date.setText(dateFormat.format(c.getTime()));
```

Comment: show your response @pappya

Comment: are you getting any error? where are you stuck?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032967/json-date-to-java-date

Answer (score 0):

```
String createdate = 
     new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(
            new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse (yourDate);
holder.date.setText(createdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `SimpleDateFormat`

```
try {
            DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
            DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            Date date = originalFormat.parse("21-12-2016");
            String formattedDate = targetFormat.format(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {

        }
```