# Gson: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2018-04-09T09:00:00+02:00"

Tags: java, timezone, gson, simpledateformat, parseexception

How can I parse a string date in the format:

```
"2018-04-09T09:00:00+02:00"
```

Gson uses:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.US)
```

But it gives the following exception:

```
    com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 2018-04-09T09:00:00+02:00
    at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:107)
    at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:82)
    at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:35)
    at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:58)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:95)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:183)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:95)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:183)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:805)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:743)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2018-04-09T09:00:00+02:00"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)
    at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:105)
    ... 52 more
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON date to Java date? [duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032967/json-date-to-java-date)

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Furthermore the modern `OffsetDateTime` class will parse your string without any explicit formatter. It couldn’t be easier.

Comment: I can't use modern date time because I'm working on an old project on JVM 6. So I have to use SimpleDateFormat, or something compatible with JVM 6.

Comment: You can, Alessandro C. `java.time` is available for Java 6 (and 7) in [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). I am myself hesitating when it comes to external dependencies, but this one seems solid and future-proof to me.

Answer (score 1):

You put the `Z` inside quotes (`'Z'`). If you [take a look at the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), you'll see that:

> Text can be quoted using single quotes (') to avoid interpretation

This means that your formatter is expecting the letter `Z` (and not some other value like `+02:00`), and that's why you're getting the error.

In the same javadoc page we can see that the pattern letter to parse offsets (the `+02:00` part) is `X`, so your formatter should be like this:

```java
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX", Locale.US);
```

As noticed in the comments, the pattern `X` was introduced only in java 7. In older versions, the only way is to split the string and set the offset in the formatter as a `TimeZone`:

```java
String input = "2018-04-09T09:00:00+02:00";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*)([\\+|\\-]\\d{2}:\\d{2})");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if (matcher.find()) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
    // timezone will be GMT+02:00
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT" + matcher.group(2)));
    // parse date without the offset part
    Date date = sdf.parse(matcher.group(1));
}
```

---

As said in the comments, you can also use the threeten backport: http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/

That's a backport to java 8's date/time classes, and it's much better and easier to use:

```java
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-04-09T09:00:00+02:00");
```

And if you still need to use `java.util.Date`, is easy to do the conversion:

```java
Date date = DateTimeUtils.toDate(odt.toInstant());
```

Comment: I’m afraid that [the Java 6 `SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) doesn’t know the `X` format pattern letter. It was only introduced in Java 7. I recommend the backport in this case.

Comment: You're right, I've added a new code for java 6, thanks!