# Java: Unparseable date error

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, parseexception

I have a date in the following format:

```
2017-04-09T11:15:39.200+03:00
```

I used the following format string:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
```

But i am getting an exception"

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-04-09T11:15:39.200+03:00"
```

Thanks

Comment: Why did you put ‘Z’ at the end of your pattern? That means your date time String has to end in the character Z and clearly it doesn’t.

Comment: remove 'z' it's useless

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Furthermore the modern `OffsetDateTime` class will parse your string without any explicit formatter. It couldn’t be easier.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong is that you didn't read the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

You'd see that the pattern to use is `X`:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
```

And you also didn't check in stackoverflow before posting: **in the same tags you used** (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/simpledateformat), there's another question - a very recent one, asked today - with basically the same problem (using `'Z'` inside quotes):

[Gson: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2018-04-09T09:00:00+02:00"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49729711/gson-java-text-parseexception-unparseable-date-2018-04-09t0900000200)

Answer (score 0):

The API docs for what you say you want shows this as the for-matter for your output wish.

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html